# How can I pass multiple arguments to script invoked within screen command?

Tags: bash, arguments, gnu-screen

I am creating a detached screen, player, that runs the script, player.sh, which has multiple arguments from AR, array.

```
AR=('foo' 'bar' 'space' 'bat')
screen -S player -dm bash -c "/home/deanresin/scripts/player.sh ${AR[@]}"
```

but it gets parsed as...

```
+ screen -S player -dm bash -c '/home/deanresin/scripts/player.sh foo' bar space bat
```

and only the first argument, foo, is passed to player.sh.

If I manually enter the array it works..

```
screen -S player -dm bash -c "/home/deanresin/scripts/player.sh foo bar space bat"

+ screen -S player -dm bash -c '/home/deanresin/scripts/player.sh foo bar space bat'
```

and they all get passed to player.sh.

Please help, I've been pulling my hair out.

edit:

I also tried..

```
screen -S player -dm bash -c "/home/deanresin/scripts/player.sh "`echo "${AR[@]}"`
```

with the same unwanted result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easier if you don't try to add the indirection via `bash -c`:

```
screen -S player -dm /home/deanresin/scripts/player.sh "${AR[@]}"
```

---

If you ever do need to nest it in a `bash -c`, you should escape the arguments properly and concatenate them into that single argument:

```
screen -S player -dm bash -c "/home/deanresin/scripts/player.sh $(printf "%q " "${AR[@]}")"
```

or pass them as separate arguments that become available as `$@` in the script string itself, which much be carefully quoted to ensure it's literal:

```
screen -S player -dm bash -c '/home/deanresin/scripts/player.sh "$@"' _ "${AR[@]}"
```

The wrong solution is using `bash -c "/home/deanresin/scripts/player.sh ${AR[*]}"` instead to concatenate all the elements without escaping, but this doesn't account for shell metacharacters and is therefore best avoided.

Comment: I tried your preferred first suggestion and it worked.  Though I'm confused what `bash -c` indirection is for.  I thought you needed it to state you were sending a bash command.  I'm ignorant as to what it is really for.